# perl combine map and each

Tags: perl

I was just wondering if this is posssible:

```
use Modern::Perl;

my @list = ('a' .. 'j');

map { func($_) } each(@list);

sub func {
  my ($index, $value) = @_;
  say "$index => $value";
}
```

Comment: Erm....what are you trying to do, exactly?  [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) applies a subroutine reference to each element of a list and returns the transformed list.

Comment: *"I was just wondering if this is posssible: [code]"* - Many things are possible, including pizza quattro stagioni with vanilla sauce. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No you can't, because `each` returns a key/value pair each time it is called. You are calling it just once, so it will pass `(0, $list[0])` to the `map`, and the subroutine will be called once for each value.

If you want to call `func` with each key/value pair you can write

```
map { func($_, $list[$_]) } keys @list;
```

but that is misusing `map` because it is meant for mapping one list to another. You should use `for` instead like this

```
func($_, $list[$_]) for keys @list;
```

You could also use `each` like this

```
my ($i, $v);
func($i, $v) while ($i, $v) = each @list;
```

Comment: or `while ( my ($i, $v) = each @list ) { func($i,$v) }`

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward approach is:

```
func($_, $a[$_]) for 0..$#a;
```

Comment: or `use Algorithm::Loops 'MapCar'; &MapCar(\&func, [keys @a], [values @a]);`

Answer (score 2):

In list context, `each @array` returns a list with two elements -- an array index and the value of the array element at that index. Calling

```
map { ... } each @array
```

is thus like

```
($index,$value) = each @array;
map { ... } ($index,$value);
```

which is probably not what you want. If `func` is supposed to take an index argument and a value argument, then maybe you want to do something like

```
map { func($_, $list[$_]) } 0 .. $#list;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `for`:

```
for ( my $index = 0; $index < scalar @list; $index++ ){
   my $value = $list[$index];
   say "$index => $value";
}
```

Comment: I hate `keys` for same reason I hate `@lines = <$file>`.

Comment: `for my $index (0..$#list)` does not flatten -- it's a counting loop, not a foreach loop -- and it's more readable than C-style.

Answer (score 0):

You are treating `map` as a loop, discarding the return values. In that case, you might as well use a loop. However, you cannot use `each @list` as a loop condition like that, because it will not expand into a full list. From `perldoc -f each`:

> When called in list context, returns a 2-element list consisting of
>   the key and value for the next element of a hash, or the index and
>   value for the next element of an array, so that you can iterate over
>   it.

Also, you are passing only a single value to your subroutine, not both. Your `each` statement expands into a list of two elements, the next index and element of the array. But `map` takes only one of those per iteration. So you get the output:

```
Use of uninitialized value $value in concatenation...
0 =>
Use of uninitialized value $value in concatenation...
a =>
```

What you probably want is something like this:

```
func($_) for keys @list;

sub func {
    my $index = shift;
    say "$index => $list[$index]";
}
```

`keys` can be used in this fashion to get the indexes of an array.